# How to get serial number of current record in SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

Please be aware that the question concerns **debugging**.

I have a code similar to following

```
 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Connection string")) {
                cn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand()) {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select aField from ATABLE";
                    using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                        while (rd.Read()) {
                            Debug.Print(rd[0].ToString());
                            // other record processing code
 }}}}
```

When I break code execution in the middle of `while` cycle can I get the number of records already processed? I don't mind digging to any deep of `SqlDataReader` guts because I am **debugging**. When writing a production code I would have just added some counter.

Imagine a situation that I have just pressed Break All (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd>) and I want to now where I am. I am aware that a breakpoint can count hits but this is not the answer. I am also aware of [RecordsAffected Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/1568z2k1(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx) but it "is  not set until all rows are read and you close the `SqlDataReader`"

The question is whether `SqlDataReader` somewhere inside counts processed records.

Comment: _" I am aware that a breakpoint can count hits but this is not the answer."_ Why? You are asking a question about debugging, so the first place where i'd look is the debugger.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It iis necessary to set a breakpoint/tracepoint in advance (and it probably slows down code execution). I am targeting situation when *I have just pressed Break*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [Inside the `SqlDataReader`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs,d576786f0fd1b1dc), there is no state regarding the number of processed rows. It is an forward stream, so it doesn't hold cache for already processed rows either.

I would suggest to create a counter integer where necessary in your own code, or write a wrapper around the data reader.

Comment: I was afraid of that. However a counter is not the solution. I am dealing with debugging some code written long ago and there is no intention to change it. To add a temporary counter just while debugging is not too convenient.